# Switch always hits Default Case JS

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a very simple switch block, and I have a very strict set of options that can possibly be put into it. The switch block is as follows...

```
const handleOption = (option) => {
        setSortBy(option)
        switch (option){
            case("DAR"):
                setTitle('Delivered and Recieved')
            case('DCR'):
                setTitle('Delivery Completion Rate')
            case('POD'):
                setTitle('Photo on Delivery Rate')
            case('CC'):
                setTitle('Call Compliance')
            case('SC'):
                setTitle('Scan Compliance')
            case('FICO'):
                setTitle('FICO')
            case('cdf'):
                setTitle('Customer Feedback')
            default:
                console.log(option)
                setTitle(option)
        }
        setTitle(option)
    }
```

As you see, I have a console.log statement under the default case. Whenever anything goes into this function expression, it will hit the default and be logged. Thus far I have had every possible case option logged, as every single one hits the default. Meaning, `'DAR'`, `'DCR'`, `'POD'`, all the rest. I'm certainly no expert on Switch cases, I seldom use them, but that's mainly because this exact issue always happens and I don't know why nor where to find the answer

Comment: You forgot to put `break;` statements.  [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: Are you sure it isn't also doing all of the `setTitle` calls after the expected `case`?

Comment: I got it-- The issue was that I needed to `return setTitle(//whatever)` instead of just having `setTitle(//whatever)` So I guess just return whatever you plan on doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `switch` you could build a little dictionary object, and then reference the values using the key. It's a little less unwieldy.

```js
const obj = {
  DAR: 'Delivered and Recieved',
  DCR: 'Delivery Completion Rate'
};

function setTitle(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

function handleOption(option) {
  setTitle(obj[option]);
}

handleOption('DAR');
handleOption('DCR');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a `break` statement after each `case` is finished.

```js
const handleOption = (option) => {
  setSortBy(option)
  switch (option) {
    case ("DAR"):
      setTitle('Delivered and Recieved');
      break;
    case ('DCR'):
      setTitle('Delivery Completion Rate');
      break;
    case ('POD'):
      setTitle('Photo on Delivery Rate');
      break;
    case ('CC'):
      setTitle('Call Compliance');
      break;
    case ('SC'):
      setTitle('Scan Compliance');
      break;
    case ('FICO'):
      setTitle('FICO');
      break;
    case ('cdf'):
      setTitle('Customer Feedback');
      break;
    default:
      console.log(option)
      setTitle(option)
  }
  setTitle(option)
}
```